# Resize imageview on onDoubleTapEvent

Tags: android, resize, imageview

I want to resize an `ImageView` on `doubleTapEvent`. A code example will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myImage"
android:src="@drawable/myPicture"
android:layout_width="64sp"
android:layout_height="64sp"
/>
```

Java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnDoubleTapListener{
    private ImageView img;

    private static int NEW_WIDTH = 100;
    private static int NEW_HEIGHT = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
        this.img = findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        img.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e){
        this.img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT));
    }
```

Something like this...

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. now i want to give zoom-in and zoom-out effect on doubleTapEvent. Thanks again

Comment: This is wrong **Answer** you can't set onDoubleTapListener on `ImageView`

Comment: It's not a method it's an interface that any class can inherit from

Answer (score 2):

Above code is not working give error on  img.setOnDoubleTapListener(this) line ...
give such type of error 
"The method setOnDoubleTapListener(this) is the undefined for the type ImageView".