# single touch movement and scaling image in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am developing one application with drawing and all, One problem I am facing is I want **single touch scaling image**. I have done image scaling with multi touch but I am so stuck with single touch.

Example :-
 I have one Rectangle on canvas. Now I want to scale and rotate that Rectangle with its one corner with one finger. I am finding this on google but not get perfect materiel or demo and else.

Please help me to find this.

Comment: Check [this post][1] for similar question previously.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204373/resize-imageview-on-ondoubletapevent

Answer (score 2):

For zooming with single touch this will help you

http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/